# POST JSON MULTIDIMENSIONAL PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have try to create post curl json array multidimensional but the result is **NULL**

i dont know why is not working.
this is my code

```
$d = array('code' => 1111, 'number' => "08813812");
$array = array('content' => $d);
$result =  json_encode($d);
// echo $result;

$data = array( 
    'content' => $d,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/receive-callback.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 701ab5b6-002e-a982-0cfd-c6eee34ae7e1",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

this is for receive the post

```
$d = $_POST['content'];
// file_put_contents('hehe.txt', $d);
print(json_encode($d, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
// $ho = json_decode($d);
// echo $d['code'];
```

in this case , i want the result in receiver is value from object array **content**

Comment: on the sending side, you should set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to `json_encode($data)` and you dont need `$array` and `$result`.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg but the result is **null**

Comment: Thats because the receiving side bombs (as you can see from @Rakesh's answer). Tool yourself up to debug properly ... as in good IDE with Xdebug support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with the following:-

```
$d = array('code' => 1111, 'number' => "08813812");
$array = array('content' => $d);
$result =  json_encode($d);
// echo $result;

$data = array( 
    'content' => $d
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/stackoverflow/receive-callback.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 701ab5b6-002e-a982-0cfd-c6eee34ae7e1",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

To receive use the follwoing :-

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```